# Resizing floated first div's based on second floated div contents?

Tags: html, css, resize

I want to have to floated columns side-by side. If second column has contents then the first column should resize its content based on the second column, is that possible with CSS? Widths are not defined.

Comment: Several methods using CSS are discussed here http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/; as can be seen there are no simple straightforward solutions that make use of CSS only. I've found the following jQuery plugin useful http://tsvensen.github.io/equalize.js/

Comment: Did you end up resolving your issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using javascript but not with straight CSS. Here are some ways to do it:

Using javascript:

```
var rightDiv = document.getElementById("straightJ2");
var rightWidth = rightDiv.clientWidth;
var leftDiv = document.getElementById("straightJ1");
if($('#straightJ2').text() || rightDiv.hasChildNodes()) {
    leftDiv.style.width = rightWidth + "px";
}
```

Or more minimal (and possibly overwhelming/hard to follow) javascript:

```
if($('#minimal2').text() || $('#minimal2').firstChild) {document.getElementById("minimal1").style.width = document.getElementById("minimal2").clientWidth + "px";}
```

Using jQuery:

```
if($('#secondColumnId').html() != '')
{
    $('#firstColumnId').width($('#secondColumnId').width());
}
```

Each of these check the second div for text or a child element and change the width of the first if one of those conditions is met

All examples can be found used in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbjPQ/)

Comment: If you want to set the element's heights equal as well you'd simply switch out `height` for `width`